# Creating an excel array having unque values

Tags: arrays, excel, duplicates, unique

I would like to clean-up an excel array by padding zeros for non-zero duplicate values.

For example, an array having arbitrary positive integers {1;0;5;0;4;0;6;4;0;5} should result in {1;0;5;0;4;0;6;0;0;0} when the non-zero duplicate elements are replaced by zeros.

A similar array say, {1;"";5;"";4;"";6;4;"";5} should result in {1;"";5;"";4;"";6;"";"";""} when the duplicate numbers are padded by null strings.

Could it be done using excel functions only?
Your kind help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  A       B
----------------   
|  1   |  1   | 
----------------       Formule in B1=
|  0   |  2   | 
----------------       =IFERROR(SMALL($A$2:$A$9,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,0)+ROW(A1)),"")
|  2   |  3   | 
----------------
|  0   |  4   | 
----------------
|  3   |  5   | 
----------------
|  4   |  6   | 
----------------
|  0   |      | 
----------------
|  5   |      | 
----------------
|  6   |      | 
----------------
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your solution seems to require multiple cells, each cell producing only one element due to the SMALL function and COUNTIF functions. This is different from the above-specified resultant array(size Nx1). The input array and the zero-padded resultant array should be the same size, namely Nx1.

Comment: Hence, my question is really about manipulating arrays (zero-padding elements) within a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332

=SUBSTITUTE(A2,0,"")

{1;0;5;0;4;0;6;4;0;5}   {1;;5;;4;;6;4;;5}

Comment: Sorry but I do not follow how this solves the problem.